# How query cassandra using static column?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I have defined locationtype as a static column.

I would like to filter data on static column.

```
select count(*) from device_stats_by_location where locationtype = "garage";
```

But I am facing exception -

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Predicates on non-primary-key columns (locationtype) are not yet supported for non secondary index queries"
```

So attempted ...

```
cqlsh:device_data> CREATE INDEX locationtype_indx on device_stats_by_location (locationtype);
```

which generated error message ...

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Secondary indexes are not allowed on static columns"
```

My question is - how can I use static column in CQL query ?

Comment: Why did you use static column ? what is your use case ?

Comment: locationtype is fixed for all the rows with same partition key

Comment: Data Model => **locationid(Pk), endof10minwindow (Ck1) , devicecategory (Ck2) , devicecount , locationtype (S)  , region (S)**  =>  for a given locationid  there will be say 2000 rows clustered together which will have same locationtype and region  => thats why **specified them as static**  =>  whats the best approach to query the data by locationtype ?

Answer (score 1):

**In Cassandra, you can't filter data with static column, can't create index and  materialized view on static column.**

You can do use use any of the below solution

- Change the static column to regular column and create index or materialized view
- Create Another table and make the locationtype as partition key and locationid, endof10minwindow, devicecategory as clustering key. Whenever you insert/update on the base table, also insert/update on this table. Now you can filter data with locationtype.